# Python websockets library: send taking a long time

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio

For some reason, calls to `websocket.send` occasionally take 10s+ in a blocking manner. The amount of data sent is never more than 10K. How is this possible?

It appears to be doing so in a blocking manner because it cannot be timeoutd out with async.wait_for.

```
await websocket.send(json.dumps(obj))
```

This is not a duplicate of [Python asyncio.sleep takes much longer than expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67977172/python-asyncio-sleep-takes-much-longer-than-expected), which doesn't deal with why websocket.send is slow.